# If $X$ is separable, then $\mathcal{F}(X)$ is also separable, where $\mathcal{F}(X) = \overline{span \{ \delta_x : x \in X \}}$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a Banach space. For any $x \in X$, define the set $\mathcal{F}(X) = \overline{span \{ \delta_x : x \in X \}}$ where $\delta_x(f)=f(x)$ for all $f \in$ Lip$_0(X)$.

The set Lip$_0(X)$ is the set of all real-valued Lipschitz functions which vanish at $0$.

Note that $\delta_x$ is an evaluation functional on Lip$_0(X)$.

I am wondering whether the following statement is true or not.

> If $X$ is separable, then $\mathcal{F}(X)$ is also separable.

The statement above is taken from [here](http://kaltonmemorial.missouri.edu/docs/sm2003c.pdf), so I believe the statement is true. But I have no idea on how to prove it.

UPDATE: The following is my attempt:

Take the set $\{ \delta_x : x \in X \}$ with the norm $\| \delta_x \| = \| x \|$. Note that $\{ \delta_x : x \in X \}$ is isometric to $X$. Hence, $\mathcal{F}(X)$ is separable.

Is it correct?

Comment: Do you claim that the map $x\to\delta_x$ is onto? The paper you mentioned says this map is an isometric embedding of $X$ into ${\cal F}(X)$, so perhaps ${\cal F}(X)$ can be a bigger space.

Comment: @uniquesolution: I see. So I am not in the right track.

Comment: @uniquesolution: Is it possible to continue my argument, where 'Take the set $\{ \delta_x : x \in X \}$ with the norm $\| \delta_x \| = \| x \|$. ' to complete the proof?

Comment: I haven't thought about it. Why don't you try?

Comment: It may be difficult, since $x \mapsto \delta_x$ is not linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is over $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $A$ denote a countable dense subset of $X$. Let $y$ be an element of  ${\cal F}(X)$, and let $\varepsilon>0$. By definition, there exists a finite linear combination $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \delta_{x_k}$ that belongs to an open ball of radius $\varepsilon/2$ around $y$ in $\mathrm{Lip}_0(X)^*$. For every $f$, and every choice of $z_k\in A$:
$$\left|\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k(\delta_{x_k}-\delta_{z_k})\right)(f)\right|=\left|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k(f(x_k)-f(z_k))\right|\leq||f||_{Lip}\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|\,\|x_k-z_k\|_X$$
Hence,
$$\left\|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k(\delta_{x_k}-\delta_{z_k})\right\|_{\mathrm{Lip}_0(X)^*} \leq \sum_{k=1}^n|a_k| \, \|x_k-z_k\|_X$$
As $A$ is dense in $X$, we can choose $z_k$ so that the r.h.s is less that $\varepsilon/2$. It follows that the distance between $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\delta_{z_k}$ and $y$ in $\mathrm{Lip}_0(X)^*$ is at most $\varepsilon$. One further approximation argument shows that the set of finite linear combinations $\sum_{k=1}^nr_k\delta_{z_k}$ with rational $r_k$'s, is dense in ${\cal F}(X)$. As this set is countable, it follows that ${\cal F}(X)$ is separable.